# JQuery fadeIn fade Out issue

Tags: jquery

i have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/VCorreia44/G4Kjr/
My problem is when I click the first button starts the fadeIn fadeOut effect, but when I click the second the effect don't stop immediately.Thanks for your help in advance.

```
<dt id="t1">Hello World</dt>
<button type="submit" onclick="myFunction()">...</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="Pause()">...</button>
```

---

```
var data_val1 = 1;
var timer;

function myFunction() {

    if (data_val1 < 1) {
        document.getElementById("t1").style.color = "#000000";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("t1").style.color = "#FF0000";
        $("#t1").fadeOut("slow").fadeIn("slow");
        timer = setTimeout('myFunction()', 1000);
    }
};

function Pause() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
}
```

Comment: That is an awful way to do that animation!

Comment: why getElementById when you use jQuery selector in the next line??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for `setTimeout()` - don't chain your fade functions, use callbacks. Also, since your using jQuery, you might as well be consistent and take advantage of `css()`:

```
function myFunction() {
    if (data_val1 < 1) {
        $("#t1").css({color:'#000'});
    } else {
        $("#t1").css({color:'#F00'}).fadeOut("slow", function(){
            $(this).fadeIn("slow", myFunction);
        });
    }
};
```

And to stop the fading:

```
function Pause() {
    $("#t1").stop();
};
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/G4Kjr/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add something like this to the `Pause` function:

```
$("#t1").stop();
$("#t1").css({opacity:1});
```

otherwise the animation will continue until the animation reaches full opacity.  If you just want to stop it in it's current position, you could just `$("#t1").stop();`

Also, you're using jQuery, so you should change `document.getElementById("t1").style.color` to `$("$t1").css({color:someColor});`

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AM5zV/)**

[Read more about jQuery's **.stop()**](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach to the problem:

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2eUuA/)

**HTML:**

```
<dt id="t1">Hello World</dt>
<button class="anim-start">Start</button>
<button class="anim-stop">Stop</button>
```

**jQuery:**

```
function animate(){
    $("#t1").fadeOut('slow').fadeIn('slow', animate);
}

$(".anim-start").on("click", function(){
    $("#t1").css("color", "red");
    animate();
});

$(".anim-stop").on("click", function(){
    $("#t1").css("color", "").css("opacity", 1).stop(true);
});
```

Clean and working!

Comment: No problem! We all been through it! You'll be learning a lot here in SO.